# A $k$-form is thought of as measuring the flux through an infinitesimal k-parallelepiped

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms

On the wikipedia has written "A $k$-form is thought of as measuring the flux through an infinitesimal k-parallelepiped." How does a $k$-form do this? if this sentence is right, then the flux of which object is measured by $k$-form?

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time.